# How do I subtract two pandas datetime series DataFrames from each other when the index is a datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, machine-learning

I am trying to subtract the values of two pandas datetime series DataFrames from each other in which the index for both DataFrames is a datetime value.

The two DataFrames in question have the same amount of columns. I want to subtract the value in the column in the second DataFrame from the value in the of the column in the first DataFrame to create a new DataFrame with the new subtracted values for the column represented in the second DataFrame.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

In[]: y
Out[]:            price
        Date
     2010-08-29   .0648
     2010-08-30   .0751
               ...
    2897 rows × 1 columns

In[]: type(y)
Out[]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

These are the values I want to subtract from y values above:

```
In[]: test = pd.DataFrame(est.predict(X))
      test
Out[]:                     0

         2010-08-29    -5.851237
         2010-08-30    -6.835347
         2010-08-31    -9.949124
                   ...
          2897 rows × 1 columns
```

When I attempt the `pd.sub()` operations on the data above I am returned a DataFrame full of NaN values as such:

```
In[]: vals = y.sub(test)
      vals 
Out[]:                price    0    
           Date
        2010-08-29     NaN    NaN
        2010-08-30     NaN    NaN
                   ...
         2897 rows × 2 columns
```

How can I subtract the values from the two columns to get an output such as the output below?

```
1      1.544535
2     -1.945362
3     -3.037018
4      0.882884
    ...
Name: newFrame, Length: 200, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Have you tried to rename the column in `test` (name the column 'price' as in `y`)?

Comment: @Ben.T how do i rename a colum in a datetime DataFrame?

Comment: you can do it when creating the dataframe `test` such as: `test = pd.DataFrame(est.predict(X),columns=['price'])`

Comment: @Ben.T, that was it. Wanna mark it as an answer so I can give you the score?

Comment: Why not just subtract the column, not the dataframe? `df.price - test[0]`.  This will allow you to change the structure of `test` and is not reliant on dataframe structure

Comment: @user3483203 good point. will these let me put the new values into a series.Series?? Doing it the way Ben.T explained now Im trying to figure out how to conver the DataFrame into a series. how do you think I can go about doing that?

Comment: Yes, subtracting two series would return a series, so you could reassign that to the `price` column, or do whatever you would like with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub` between two dataframes will work if columns have the same name so here for example, create the dataframe `test` by:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(est.predict(X),columns=['price'])
```